# The justification of the ansatz for the reduced density matrix of ground state of coupled harmonic oscillator

Tags: entanglement-entropy

For coupled harmonic oscillator, the Hamiltonian is :
$$H=\frac{1}{2}(\pi_{i}^2+K_{ij}\phi_{i}\phi_{j})$$
From the Hamiltonian, we can calculate the ground state wave function. If we then can take a subset of the degrees of freedom and calculate the reduced density matrix for it in principle, then we can calculate the entanglement entropy. But some method can make the calculation very simple:
first, you propose an ansatz for the reduced density matrix:
$$\rho=c e^{-\Sigma \epsilon_{l} a_{l}^{\dagger}a_{l}}$$.
where $a_{l} $ and $a_{l}^{\dagger}$ are related to $\phi_{i}$ and $\pi_{i}$ by linear Bogoliubov transformation.

If you use the above ansatz, the calculation can be very simple.

My question is that what is the justification of the above ansatz. Why we can choose the above ansatz?